# Google Picker API not showing more than 50 documents

Tags: pagination, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-picker

I have been using the Google Picker API to select files from Drive for some quite time. However, it turns out that for folders with more than 50 elements, it shows only the first 50.

I was wondering if there is a configuration parameter to set this limit higher or call a *next* function to paginate results. I have looked through their documentation and could not find any reference to such things.

This is my code:

```js
function createPicker() {

        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
            var view = new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true);

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
                .setAppId(appId)
                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                .addView(view)
                .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .build();

            picker.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. This is intended behaviour: Picker is limited to 50 files/folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Picker is limited to 50 files or folders**, but you can use the search box to look for files that are not listed.

This was recently reported on Issue Tracker:

- [Issue Tracker #154271159: Google Picker unable load/display more than 50 files in same folder](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153107053)